# Distribute divs evenly in a horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to distribute divs evenly in a horizontal line.  I will have 3 divs on maximum width of the screen.  When I resize the browser and it can't fit 3 then it will switch to two, and then one.  I have found a few examples of how this is done, but none of them do it in the way I am looking for.  For example what I want is this:

Full Screen width:

```
[------------------------------------------]
[   [--------]   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[                                          ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[------------------------------------------]
```

Resized width:

```
[-----------------------------]
[   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[                             ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[                             ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [        ]   [        ]   ]
[   [--------]   [--------]   ]
[-----------------------------]
```

Note that the divs are centered on the page every time.

What I was able to find are these examples which force the divs to be left and right with the borders of the div and then space is evently distributed such as example below:

```
[-----------------------------]
[[--------]         [--------]]
[[        ]         [        ]]
[[        ]         [        ]]
[[--------]         [--------]]
[                             ]
[[--------]         [--------]]
[[        ]         [        ]]
[[        ]         [        ]]
[[--------]         [--------]]
[                             ]
[[--------]         [--------]]
[[        ]         [        ]]
[[        ]         [        ]]
[[--------]         [--------]]
[-----------------------------]
```

Here are the code examples of what I tried:

- http://jsfiddle.net/k9FqG/  --- This one only works cause of
  text-align, but that doesn't work on divs, just text.  I need text to
  stay aligned left.  This also does not drops the divs when I resize
  browser.
- http://radiatingstar.com/distribute-divs-images-equaly-line
- http://jsfiddle.net/BYEw5/  --- This one only works cause of
  text-align, but that doesn't work on divs, just text.  I need text to
  stay aligned left.  This also does not drops the divs when I resize
  browser.

Comment: You need to post code here of what you've tried.

Comment: I have, look at js fiddles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope this is what you are trying to do with!!!

**CSS**

```
#container {
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#container > div {
 width: calc(100% / 6);  
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;   
 border:1px solid red;
 text-align:center;
 margin:2%;    
 padding:20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

See it in action at  http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/1

Comment: Thanks for the effort but no this was not it.  Your left and right div are sitting next to the edge cause a big gap in the middle when there is only 2 divs in a line.  I need them to be centered from the edges as I've shown in the image example in question.

Comment: What if you don't know the number of divs and can't hard-code `calc(100% / 6)`?

Comment: you can calculate the length of the children using jqery or javascript like http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/235/

Answer (score 4):

All modern browsers now support also flexible content (pure css). If you dont know the number of elements before hand:

```
#container {
  justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around;
}
```

See here 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/